# Why does tilda disappear on typing forward slash in shell?

Tags: bash, pureos

I recently noticed that on my new PureOS terminal - I am not able to type tilda followed by forward slash. The tilda and the slash disappear! Only if I input a space after tilda, then I am able to input tilda followed by forward slash. I am using bash shell. This is not a problem on Lubuntu, Xubuntu. And I have never seen this kind of issue before.

~/  - Cannot type this sequence unless I input a space in between those two characters.
I do not have a .inputrc in my home directory and /etc/inputrc seemed fine.
Thank you for any suggestions/solutions.

Comment: Maybe it's the font used by the terminal, have you tried change it and use another one?

Comment: It is not the font. I think it is to do with keyboard configuration. I just noticed it with some other characters too. Like single quote and c - change c to a different character like ć.

Comment: What happens if you type the tilde and say, `a` or `n`? Do you get ã and ñ? "Dead keys" that combine like that are common in e.g. Finnish keymaps, which is somewhat annoying when trying to write those special characters in code. But where I've seen, usually if they don't combine, both characters appear. So e.g. tilde-n gives me `ñ`, but tilde-b gives `~b`, not just `b`. Though I suppose that could be different in different systems. Check your keymap and terminal settings.

Comment: How do I avoid these dead keys? I just changed keyboard configuration to English(US) (no selection of dead keys etc.). Still getting these key combinations. I also rebooted after running 'sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration'

Comment: that is an international keyboard that uses character composing

Answer (score 2):

After I changed the keyboard using below command:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`

I had to further select it in top right menu bar. After that, as the 'dead keys' were not selected in keyboard. It all started to work fine.

[image]